# Python: Making a wordbook to search within

Tags: python, list, search, cpu-word

I am writing a code in which I want to search a datafile with words - a wordbook. Just for fun! The idea is to define some letters, and the program will then find words containing the exact input. 
I have already written the code and succeded, but it really needs some adjustments too give the right output.

This is the code block:

```
def findword():

letters = set(str(raw_input("Type letters: ")))

for item in wordlist:      # already defined list containing the words
    if letters >= set(item):
        if len(item) <= len(letters):
            print item
```

I am using set to compare the letters with the list of words.
The problem is that the output can be words containing two of the same letter even though input may only contain one of that specific letter. So how can I make sure the output will be the exact input letters but not arranged the same way?
I'd appreciate if you would take the time to help me out with this! Thanks!

Alex

Comment: So you want to find all anagrams? Can you give example in/outputs?

Comment: So you mean if input is "water" then it would match "waater" or "watter" ?

Comment: If you could list out some inputs and expected outputs, that would probably help.  As I see Niklas just said...

Comment: @Sid: That's what it already does. I think the problem is exactly the opposite.

Comment: Oh yeah pretty important point there. 
If I type "egrat" for input, the output should be "great", "rat", "gert" and so on. As long as the output letters matches the input letters and not duplicate unless I type two of same letter.

Comment: + the output word has to be an element in the wordlist, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question in the way that if the input is, e.g., `abc`, you want to match `cba` or `bca`, but not `abcd` or `abcc`. So basically you want to find anagrams.

You can use a dictionary to keep track of the number of occurrences of each letter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_letter_dict(word):
  letters = defaultdict(int)
  for c in word:
    letters[c] += 1

letters = make_letter_dict(raw_input("Letters: "))
words = (w for w in wordlist if make_letter_dict(w) == letters)
```

Comment: Your interpretation is probably correct :) hopefully he'll give an example.

Comment: Exactly. If "abc" is input the output may not come with "acc" or "abbc". I'll try it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the arrangement of the output then generate two random number between 0 and len(outputStr-1)/2 and between len(outputStr-1)/2+1 and len(outputStr)-1 and swap them.